# Configure package source of nuget package manager in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget-package

I would like to change the package source of nuget package manager in visual studio code. Please guide me to change the package source. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `nuget.config` file in to the root of your project and specify the package source in there like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="sample" value="https://www.sample.org/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

For password protected package sources :

```
<packageSourceCredentials>
  <sample> <!--package src name-->
    <add key="Username" value="something" />
    <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="thepassword" />
  </sample>
</packageSourceCredentials>
```

Comment: i am getting error like unable to load service index for source nuget visual studio code

Comment: The reason for this issue in most cases is because the network issue or the incorrect configuration in the nuget.config. First, please open the path of the packageSources in the browser and check your network access.

Comment: getting errors like unable to get repository signature information for source and response status code does not indicate success 407 proxy authentication required

Comment: I added sample code for password protected sources. This error happen because the client lacks proper authentication credentials for a proxy server that is intercepting the request between the client and server.

Comment: now getting error the nuget package repository returned a bad response. unable to download packages

Comment: It seems like your connection to the source package server is not established.